# Can't compile/run a java project in IntelliJ

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea

### The issue:

While it was working fine yesterday. Today, I wasn't able to compile my project(spring-boot). I created a demo project to simulate the same issue that happened in my current project.

When I try to run the project using the run button It doesn't want to compile. Note all the errors from the failed compilation. Also, you can see that all dependencies are imported (see **External Libraries**):

[image]

I know I can run the app by typing `mvn spring-boot:run` in the terminal. But for some reason, I don't want to do that.

As you can see, this demo is a simple spring-boot project:

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>demox</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>demox</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

### What I 've tried:

I've tried countless solutions among them:

- Select **Build->Rebuild Project**
- Clicking **File>Invalidate caches/ restart**
- `mvn clean` -> **Build -> Make Project**
- **Maven -> Reimport**
- Deleted `.iml` file and re-imported the project
- Checked that there is no excludes in **Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Compiler | Excludes**

### About IntelliJ IDEA:

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3.4 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-193.6911.18, built on March 17, 2020
Licensed to Hamza Belmellouki
Subscription is active until October 10, 2020
For educational use only.
Runtime version: 11.0.6+8-b520.43 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
macOS 10.15.3
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 1502M
Cores: 4
Registry: debugger.click.disable.breakpoints=true, documentation.show.toolbar=true, debugger.watches.in.variables=false, compiler.automake.allow.when.app.running=true, ide.tree.collapse.recursively=false, ide.balloon.shadow.size=0
Non-Bundled Plugins: AceJump, BrowseWordAtCaret, DBN, GsonFormat, IdeaVIM, Lombook Plugin, MavenRunHelper, com.4lex4.intellij.solarized, com.alayouni.ansiHighlight, com.berzanmikaili.intellij.monokai_pro, com.codota.csp.intellij, com.daylerees.rainglow, com.github.holgerbrandl.pasteimages/, com.github.mturlo.intellij.theme.spacegray, com.github.shiraji.emoji, com.godwin.json.parser, com.intellij.ideolog, com.intellij.jira, com.intellij.plugins.html.instantEditing, com.jetbrains.CyanTheme, com.jetbrains.colorful.toolwindow.icons, com.jetbrains.darkPurpleTheme, com.jetbrains.grayTheme, com.ppolivka.gitlabprojects, com.robohorse.robopojogenerator, com.sburlyaev.terminal.plugin, com.viartemev.requestmapper, com.vincentp.gruvbox-theme, commit-template-idea-plugin, mobi.hsz.idea.gitignore, net.seesharpsoft.intellij.plugins.csv, tanvd.grazi, org.asciidoctor.intellij.asciidoc, org.intellij.scala, org.root.GoogleIt, org.sonarlint.idea, some.awesome
```

I've spent lots of time on this issue. How can I fix it?

### From comments:

Running `mvn clean install -X`:

```
Apache Maven 3.6.0 (97c98ec64a1fdfee7767ce5ffb20918da4f719f3; 2018-10-24T19:41:47+01:00)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.6.0/libexec
Java version: 1.8.0_192, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_192.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_MA, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.15.3", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
[DEBUG] Created new class realm maven.api
[DEBUG] Importing foreign packages into class realm maven.api
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.annotation.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.annotation.security.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.enterprise.inject.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.enterprise.util.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.inject.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.artifact < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.classrealm < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.cli < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.configuration < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.exception < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.execution < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.execution.scope < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.lifecycle < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.model < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.monitor < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.plugin < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.profiles < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.project < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.reporting < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.repository < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.rtinfo < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.settings < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.toolchain < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.usability < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.authentication < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.authorization < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.events < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.observers < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.proxy < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.repository < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.resource < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.classworlds < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.component < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.configuration < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.container < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.context < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.lifecycle < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.logging < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.personality < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.Xpp3Dom < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParser < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParserException < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlSerializer < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.artifact < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.collection < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.deployment < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.graph < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.impl < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.installation < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.metadata < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.repository < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.resolution < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.spi < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.transfer < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.version < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.fusesource.jansi.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.slf4j.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.slf4j.helpers.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.slf4j.spi.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG] Populating class realm maven.api
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[DEBUG] Message scheme: color
[DEBUG] Message styles: debug info warning error success failure strong mojo project
[DEBUG] Reading global settings from /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.6.0/libexec/conf/settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user settings from /Users/hamzabelmellouki/.m2/settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading global toolchains from /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.6.0/libexec/conf/toolchains.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user toolchains from /Users/hamzabelmellouki/.m2/toolchains.xml
[DEBUG] Using local repository at /Users/hamzabelmellouki/.m2/repository
[DEBUG] Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10.0 for /Users/hamzabelmellouki/.m2/repository
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[DEBUG] Using mirror central (https://nexus.sdf.x-hub.io/repository/maven-public/) for maven-releases (https://nexus.sdf.x-hub.io/repository/maven-releases).
[DEBUG] Using mirror central (https://nexus.sdf.x-hub.io/repository/maven-public/) for maven-snapshots (https://nexus.sdf.x-hub.io/repository/maven-snapshots).
[DEBUG] Using mirror central (https://nexus.sdf.x-hub.io/repository/maven-public/) for central (http://central).
[DEBUG] Extension realms for project com.example:demox:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: (none)
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecycle mappings for packaging jar from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
[DEBUG] Using mirror central (https://nexus.sdf.x-hub.io/repository/maven-public/) for sonatype-nexus-snapshots (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots).
[DEBUG] Using mirror central (https://nexus.sdf.x-hub.io/repository/maven-public/) for central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2).
[DEBUG] Using mirror central (https://nexus.sdf.x-hub.io/repository/maven-public/) for apache.snapshots (https://repository.apache.org/snapshots).
[DEBUG] Extension realms for project org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.2.6.RELEASE: (none)
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecycle mappings for packaging pom from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
[DEBUG] Extension realms for project org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:pom:2.2.6.RELEASE: (none)
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecycle mappings for packaging pom from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
[DEBUG] === REACTOR BUILD PLAN ================================================
[DEBUG] Project: com.example:demox:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[DEBUG] Tasks:   [clean, install]
[DEBUG] Style:   Regular
[DEBUG] =======================================================================
```

Comment: do ```mvn clean install -X```. It will give you details of the execution and then may be post a screenshot of that here so that we can take a look if you are still not able to fix it.

Comment: Are you getting just these many logs ?

Comment: I can't paste everything since stack overflow doesn't support more than 30000 chars

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Hamzablm/bcee101487c7ddb13bc0fc2d1706bf62 You can see everything here

Comment: I am not getting the issue. The logs you have in your git says BUILD SUCCESS

Comment: Indeed, The problem is not in the deps. they're surely in .m2 but IntelliJ couldn't figure them out.

Comment: all maven commands work fine. However, spring-boot run/debug edit configuration in IntelliJ doesn't work. And I need that to work for testing reasons.

Comment: Could you please try 2020.1 version from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/ and to run IDE with default settings: use File | Manage Settings | **Restore Default Settings...** action to reset them in 2020.1 version. Also please make sure you have `path.macros.xml` file exists in <IDE config>/options directory, see [this comment](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-239150#focus=streamItem-27-4117814.0-0).

Comment: You've saved my day. Thank you!!

Comment: Great to know it works now! Has the settings reset helped or re-creating the `path.macros.xml` file?

Comment: Yes! Please, see below all the steps I've done

Comment: Sadly nothing worked for me. Went through all solutions presented here, nothing helped. What a frustration!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Thanks to Andry's comment my issue was solved.
Here are the steps I've done:

1. Export IDE settings(keymaps, plugins). You can export it by going to **File | Manage IDE settings | Export Settings...** It will export a zip file that you can later import it when you restore default IDE configuration
2. Go to **File | Manage IDE settings | Restore Default Settings...** the IDE will restart and will be restored to the default configuration. this command re-generated `path.macros.xml` file that was missing with the right configuration. Note that you can file in `<IDE config>/options` directory
3. Import the exported zip file **File | Manage IDE settings | Import Settings...**

Comment: This is the new "invalidate cache and restart" =))

Comment: Unfortunately it did not help me to resolve the same issue

Comment: I faced this terrible situation too. But its very sad that we have to resort to such disruptive solution! Hope Intellij guys do something about this

Answer (score 1):

I pulled my hair for an hour on this. At the end, it turned out Intellij was using a different maven home than what maven is actually using. The library was not actually present in that intellij specific .m2 folder. This discrepancy is exposed only after you do "**Invalidate Caches and Restart**" and then the IDE starts showing those dependencies in red.

Answer (score 1):

Using 2022.2.1 and same issue was here.

After two days of pulling my hairs, nothing (incl. cache invalidation, reimport, restart, reload, rebuild, IDE version upgrade/downgrade...) but one worked!

I created problematic Spring Boot projects via New Project wizard of IntelliJ. After applying all suggestions offered here and there, as a last bullet, I created a new project via [Spring initializr](https://start.spring.io/) and reimported as a new module. Bingo!

I don't know what's being fixed but, that weird exception gone!

Answer (score 0):

Steps you can take:

1. Delete `.m2` folder
2. Try to run `mvn clean install` to install all of your dependencies.

For IntelliJ, configure for Maven

```
Run/Debug Configurations -> Maven -> Command Line: clean install
```

For running Spring Boot:

```
Run/Debug Configurations -> Spring Boot
```

[Code Coverage](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000178680-Code-coverage-for-applications):

```
Run/Debug Configurations -> Spring Boot -> Code Coverage
```

Comment: Plus, I've checked that all deps are in .m2 folder.

Comment: You have written `mvn clean` in your question

Comment: Try deleting .m2 folder and run `mvn clean install` again

Comment: After deleting .m2 folder and running `mvn clean install` it doesn't compile either. I think It is an IDE-specific issue.

Comment: Try `mvn clean install` from the command line and then run `mvn spring-boot:run` to run your Spring Boot application

Comment: I mentioned in the question It runs fine in `mvn spring-boot:run` but I don't want to run it that way (for some reasons). I want to be able to run it from my IDE.

Comment: Yes I've mentioned that before

Comment: I want to run it as a spring-boot edit configuration, not a maven one. Because It allows me to use the IntelliJ code coverage tool.

Answer (score 0):

If Maven succeeds and IntelliJ fails, it would seem to me that you have to tell IntelliJ to look at the same folder as Maven for creating and running artifacts.

Go to your project settings and make sure that IntelliJ's output folder is /target, right under the root of your project.

If you have an artifact, make sure that its build path is the same as the one created by Maven.

Check your SDK while you're at it.  Make sure you have the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Maven is probably not configured properly in your Settings. Go to:

```
File > Settings... > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Maven
```

And check the values `Maven home directory`, `User settings file` and especially `Local repository` (make sure it's the same that is used when you directly do `mvn install`).

Comment: I thought s/he said Maven succeeded, but IntelliJ failed.

Comment: Well, the thing is when you convert a project to Maven project in IntelliJ it will get the dependencies needed from the local repository configured in the settings and also use those settings to download the dependencies missing, if this config is incorrect it will not be able to download the JARs but when you use Maven in the terminal it might use a different configuration which might work.

Answer (score 0):

Run into the same issue, though with a Gradle build. The problem in that case was, the IDE checks for newer versions of the artifacts / dependencies in the build.gradle file and records them, therefore your build.gradle is updated with the new version codes for the artifacts. The IDE though does not download the latest versions when doing that.

SOLUTION: Rebuild the project when online. Or check the build.gradle file for modifications and revert to the previous versions.
NOTE: This is a Gradle solution, substitute appropriately for a maven build.

Answer (score 0):

Similar Problem, turned out intellij used /.m2/repository and maven /.m2