# Package doesn't exist despite being in dependencies

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, windows-10

I have trouble using Maven, the xml file was not created by me, it and my code works fine for my tutor, even if i send her my entire project as I use it in IntelliJ.
I use IntelliJ idea Community 2020.2, Java 8,11,14 depending on what I need, I just installed Maven 3 hoping it'd fix my problem, but it didn't, at least mvn -v works from the command line now tho.

If I try to import com.opencsv it throws me the error:

`java: package com.opencsv does not exist`

IntelliJ recognizes the package and even autocompletes methods for me etc., but it always fails upon attempting compilation, both in the IntelliJ terminal and the windows command line.

I am able to run other programms through the maven terminal, and cmd.
IntelliJ recognizes com.opencsv in the dependencies.

This is my first time using maven, please be patient :*

As i said the pom and my code works for my tutor, but here's the pom anyway:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>TownDbWS1920</groupId>
    <artifactId>TownDbProgramingExercise</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>3.8</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

As i said the code is fine and works for others, but here it is anyway:

```
import com.opencsv.CSVReader;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

/**
 * Zettel 0 - Aufgabe 2
 */
public class ReadCSV_Task2 {

    private static String FILENAME = "data.csv";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("---Aufgabe 1.1---");
        fetchAll_CSV_NUM(FILENAME);
        System.out.println("---Aufgabe 1.2---");
        fetchAll_CSV_ASSOC(FILENAME);

        System.out.println("Compiled, no syntactical failures =)");
    }

    /**
     * Aufgabe 1.1
     * @param fileName die CSV-Datei
     * @return die Daten der CSV-Datei in einer Arrayliste
     */
    public static List<String[]> fetchAll_CSV_NUM(String fileName) {
        FileReader fileReader = null;
        List<String[]> words = null;
        try {
            fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        CSVReader csvReader=new CSVReader(fileReader);
        try {
            csvReader.readNext(); //read the first line to dispose of it
            words =new ArrayList<>(csvReader.readAll());//Read all the other lines into an arraylist
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return words;
    }

    /**
     * Aufgabe 1.2
     * @param fileName die CSV-Datei
     * @return die Daten der CSV-Datei in einer Mapliste
     */
    public static List<Map<String, String>> fetchAll_CSV_ASSOC(String fileName) {
        FileReader fileReader=null;
        List<Map<String, String>> maps;
        String[] headLine=null;
        List<String[]> words=null;
        try {
            fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        CSVReader csvReader=new CSVReader(fileReader);
        try {
            headLine=csvReader.readNext();//Read the first line to get the keys
            words =new ArrayList<>(csvReader.readAll());//Read the rest into a list
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        maps=new ArrayList<>();
        for(String[] line:words){//For each line
            Map<String, String> cmap= new HashMap<>();
            for(int i=0;i<line.length;i++){//Assign to a key
                cmap.put(headLine[i],line[i]);
            }
            maps.add(cmap);
        }
        return maps;
    }
}
```

Comment: *it throws me the error*: Where specifically are you getting this error? What happens if you run `mvn compile`?

Comment: I get the same error in the IntelliJ Idea terminal and the cmd. mvn compile tell me build success both in the intelliJ Idea terminal and cmd.

Comment: Can you post the full text of that error from the command line? Your dependencies seem to be correct so there must be something else going on.

Comment: As I said the error is "java: package com.opencsv does not exist". It also tells me it can't recognize the class for csvReader, I assume that's because it can't import the package: C:\Users\Name\Desktop\_JavaTemplates\src\main\java\ReadCSV_Task2.java:36:9
java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class CSVReader
  location: class ReadCSV_Task2

this 4 times of course. I get the same error in cmd and IntelliJ terminal

Comment: This might not do anything, but the latest version is "5.3".  Try changing that and see if it helps. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.opencsv/opencsv/5.3

Comment: I just replaced the 3.8 in my pom with 5.3, is that all that's required? I mvn compiled, it downloaded a bit, told me build success and then again told me the package doesn't exist.

Comment: I'm not a Maven or IntelliJ expert, but it's acting like it's being included in the build, but not as a runtime dependency.  I.e., it's expecting you to set the class path yourself.  Which might be reasonable, but you'd there there'd be an option to include dependencies at run time.  I'd ask another question about that specifically: builds OK, fails at runtime, how to include a dependency at run time.  That might be what is going on.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're trying to say, but a quick google tells me with a scope of compile the dependencies should be included at run time. IntelliJ recognizes the dependency in modules and it's set to compile scope.

Comment: Hi , I am getting the same  error  package  com.abc.xyz does not exists while executing mvn  verify  , mvn compile and mvn install cmds  .  However  IntelliJ IDE is correctly importing the package in dependent  module . Any idea what could be the issue here  ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Copying an answer i found here: [Can't compile/run a java project in IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60990976/cant-compile-run-a-java-project-in-intellij?noredirect=1#comment108874882_60990976)

Export IDE settings(keymaps, plugins). You can export it by going to File | Manage IDE settings | Export Settings... It will export a zip file that you can later import it when you restore default IDE configuration

Go to File | Manage IDE settings | Restore Default Settings... the IDE will restart and will be restored to the default configuration. this command re-generated path.macros.xml file that was missing with the right configuration. Note that you can file in /options directory

Import the exported zip file File | Manage IDE settings | Import Settings...

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you do not import `CSVReader`, nor do you use it with its fully-qualified name.

Add this line with your other imports:

```java
import com.opencsv.CSVReader;
```

EDIT: I see that you apparently have tried this, but this is why the error message you are reporting is output.

Comment: Oh I must have not properly copied my code, it has been in there from the very beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Since you say that `mvn compile` is happy but IntelliJ is not, the most likely reason is that you did not tell IntelliJ to open your code *as a Maven project*, so it isn't turning on its Maven integration. Remove this program from your IntelliJ Project (don't delete the contents, just unlink it from the IDE) and [open it as a Maven project](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/maven-support.html#maven_import_project_start).

Comment: I did it as described in that link, didn't change anything. I always have the maven sidebar, i assume that's a sign of working maven integration?