# IntelliJ: Java: Package does not exist (Maven)

Tags: java, maven, gradle, intellij-idea

I got this error several times, palying with the .m2 and .gradle directory files (too huge/deletion)

[Error.jpeg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKHgz.png)

After trying many solutions on the web error was still there... (invalidating caches, mvn clean/install, etc...)

Refer to this guy thanking "Andrey": https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/203365204/comments/360001626200

"Andrey" post: [Can't compile/run a java project in IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60990976/cant-compile-run-a-java-project-in-intellij?noredirect=1#comment108874882_60990976)

*if you follow the link chain and read carefully, you may need to play with the IDE/files (path.macros.xml) and repositories hard links in files... still wondering why it bugs out so much only for moving a couple folder for a so intelligent dev env.

thanks for any help! (it also doesn't find packages in pure java projects (no mvn/gradle))

Answer (score 0):

Instead of going through the hassle of editing many files, an "update" repository button seems to be available in the IDE.

**File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Maven > Repositories**

[Update Repository (Maven)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qwkj.png)

This fixed my problem, it redownloaded/reindexes packages.

Thanks StackOverflow!

###################################################

## # EDIT: The problem is back, in force!

I don't understand why he can't resolve a "Google" import statement, this is weird. Must be because of folders I deleted. Guess I'll need to reimport everything?
###################################################

## # EDIT2: The problem is solved!

I found out that while deleting and moving folders, I forgot to fix the folder path for the "folder library" added in the module.

I found out that the libraries added to the modules, via windows folder/browse, doesn't automatically get remapped like some using the $PROJECT_Dir.

The "now-readded" libraries are resolving fine, even at runtime.

Fix:

1. Open your problematic project.
2. Open the "Porject Structure"
3. Add a new library (see picture 1: [picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Ty6L.png))
4. Browse the "now-fixed" path
5. Apply & Reload Maven Project
6. If needed, "update" the Maven repository in "Settings" in my upper post.

Hopefully this will fix your problem too, I added some tracks in my upper post if that still doesn't fix it for you.

Good luck on your journey!